# Why can't it go through the string and give the toast? It always goes to true

Tags: android

```
    String hint = chatText.getText().toString();
    String text = "hi+";
    Boolean found;
    found = text.contains(hint);
```

//So if "hi+" is found in string it will say true

```
    if(found==true){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BoomShakalaka",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

//if its false it will bring me to this

```
    else if(found==false){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "It worked!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Can you debug your app and find out what the contents of `hint` are?

Comment: BTW your have initialized wrong way String hint="hi+"; and String text=chatText.getText().toString(); and your code will work fine , otherwise if you don't want to change the variable checkout my answer

Answer (score 2):

It should be other way around , Because you want to check weather the string(hint) contains "hi+" or not

```
found = hint.contains(text);
```

And why are you using `if` like this `found==true` there is no need

```
//make your if statement like this 
if(found){
    //Do something when found is true
}else{
    //DO something when found is false
 }
```